# Facebook Page Insights API: How specifically the way page_fans field gives out information is updated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Page Insights API and page_fans metric. I'm going to update the API version from 2.8 to 3.2. The changelog says, quote: 
Period parameters have been changed to day from lifetime for the following metrics. The lifetime period parameter will return an empty dataset.

- page_fans
- page_fans_city
- page_fans_country
- page_fans_gender_age
- page_fans_locale

The link is

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.2#page-insights

So, now I need to change the period from lifetime to day, as lifetime period really returns empty dataset.
However, please help me understand, I used to get all current likes of the page and am I getting only the likes I gained through the day? So, do I need to go through all the pages in API and sum those likes? Then what is the difference between page_fan_adds and page_fans?

Comment: If you just want the current like count for a page(?), you don’t need to delve into the insights endpoint, that is available plain and simple via the `fan_count` property of the Page object.

Comment: @04FS thanks for the reply, this is already production code. The task is to migrate from the older API version to newer. So, I'm trying to understand whether it is safe or not.